# How do I permantely plumb 5 tiki torches around my pool by placing a T on my buried propane tank which feed the pool/hot tub heater?

Tags: plumbing, propane

What is required to "T" off of my buried propane tank that feeds my pool/hot tub heater so I can permanently mount 5 tiki torches around my pool?

Comment: You'd need a "T" fitting.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are hooked up on the low pressure side of the regulator. I would bury a roll of 5/8" of type k copper line around to all torches. Usually there is 1/4" fitting you will need. That will get silver soldered to a 1/2 by 1/4 inch reducer, so you can hook up the the torches individually. Make sure your regulator is sized correctly and that 5/8" copper is the proper size! You will need to figure distance, for the burners too. Once you have that, it is real simple.

Make sure you put concrete around the posts when you bury them. Do not get the copper pipe into the concrete, it will corrode the copper.